# Problems with colorbox content (positioning) within iframe

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe, colorbox

I will try to explain the issue as best as I can.

I have completed and handed off a project that uses colorbox (a lightbox type script for those of you who have not used it) to display information when a user clicks on a link.

The team that has been given my tool loads it in an iframe on their home page.  From what they have told me, the colorbox positioning is odd depending on the size of the content in the iframe.

If the content is 'short', the colorbox displays nicely (in regards to how it is positioned).  If the content in the iframe is 'long', the colorbox is out of whack... the user must do much scrolling to actually see the colorbox content.

Code snippet below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%"});
});
```

Then in my HTML i have this:

```
<a class="iframe" href="http://LINK TO AN EXTNERAL PAGE">BLAH</a>
```

Any ideas on how to make it work (position) nicely when in iframe? I am thinking that for starters the colorbox js and css would need to be added to the parent page (the page that is loading my tool into the iframe).

If someone can help me out I would be greatful.  Sorry if I have not provided enough info or if what I have written makes no sense.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should probably call colorbax from outside.
Please check this link:
[Controlling Colorbox position inside an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7307362/controlling-colorbox-position-inside-an-iframe)

Answer (score 1):

A colorbox is mostly positioned in the center of the page. But when giving (xx)% percent width of height, this can vary. Maybe you can try to give it a (xx)px height and try it.

Comment: Hi Jeffrey

Did not work :(

Looks like there is padding or margin of some sort that is causing the issue.

Comment: @laz hmm... do you have an example on the web, or a test case. It's worth looking at it. I had simular problems, and ended up with double styling in the stylesheet. (from colorbox library).

Comment: Hey Jeffrey. Thanks for getting back to me. Looks like I found a solution. I am using the one provided at the link below (semems to work thus far): http://metaflood.com/work-life/how-to-use-the-jquery-plugin-colorbox-from-within-an-iframe/

Comment: Having said this ^^ would you like me to still post a test case?

Comment: Nice it's working now, no it's okay! I've read that information and tested it and seems to be working fine ;-)